# SchemaSpy 6.1.0 is not available on Maven central?

Tags: maven, schemaspy

I try to find it on Maven Central, but the best I can find in version 5.0.0 under **net.sourceforge.schemaspy** groupId.

I wonder if it could be available soon or later under it.

Is any one has a clue why the new project under **github** is not pushing it on it (with the new groupId **org.schemaspy**)?

Comment: I can help to make this happen, I made it for several groupId and would be happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers and we are currently working on it.

We have acquired the coordinates and started to push SNAPSHOTS to OSSRH.

We hope to have the next release 6.2.2 published to maven central.

Comment: Many thanks for making this happened.